# Oracle : Can update_set_clause be a subquery?

Tags: oracle

I have a source table in Oracle that looks something like this :

*Source Table with Data*

```
Id   | Attr_list
--   ---------              
1    | col1,col2            
2    | col3,col4            
3    | col1,col4
```

*Target table with data*

```
Id   | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
--     -----  ----- -----  -----
1    | aaa  | bbb  | ccc  | ddd  
2    | eee  | fff  | ggg  | hhh  
3    | iii  | jjj  | kkk  | lll
```

*Expected target table with Data*

```
Id   |col1  | col2| col3 | col4
--    ---    -----  -----  -----  
1    | NULL | NULL| ccc  | ddd  
2    | eee  | fff | NULL | NULL 
3    | NULL | jjj | kkk  | NULL
```

The column names of the target table are mentioned as values in the source table.
Now, I want to update the target table,  all the columns to `NULL` which are mentioned as the attribute list(attr_list) in source table , by joining the `ID`.
Could you please guide me through?

Comment: please add the expected result, it's not clear at all.

Comment: please write properly source column names and data. Target column name and data.

Comment: Could you please see if the description makes better sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  use Dynamic SQL to update the specific columns.The query inside for loop splits "," delimited values into rows.

**EDIT:** Ok, I thought to go ahead and make the changes as expected in the comment.

```
DECLARE
   v_query   VARCHAR2 (200);
BEGIN
   FOR cur IN (  SELECT b.id, b.column_name, a.DATA_TYPE
                   FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS a
                        JOIN (    SELECT DISTINCT id,
                                                  TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (attr_list,
                                                                       '[^,]+',
                                                                       1,
                                                                       LEVEL))
                                                     column_name
                                    FROM source_table
                              CONNECT BY INSTR (attr_list,
                                                ',',
                                                1,
                                                LEVEL - 1) > 0) b
                           ON A.COLUMN_NAME = UPPER (b.column_name)
                  WHERE a.table_name = 'TARGET_TABLE'
               ORDER BY id)
   LOOP
      --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      v_query :=
            'UPDATE target_table SET '
         || cur.column_name
         || ' = '
         || CASE
               WHEN cur.data_type LIKE 'VARCHAR%'
               THEN
                  'NULL'
               WHEN cur.data_type = 'NUMBER'
               THEN
                  '0'
               WHEN cur.data_type = 'DATE'
               THEN
                  'TO_DATE(''1900-01-01'',''yyyy-mm-dd'')'
            END
         || ' WHERE id = '
         || cur.id;

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: This looks great! But the initial requirement changed. Instead of **NULL**, they want **default values** specific to the datatype of the column, say for example, if attr_list - _a,b,c_ contains 3 different datatyp-ed columns (say _varchar, numeric, date_), they want the output to be set as, **set a = NULL, set b = 0 and set c = 1900-01-01**

Comment: Ok. Since this question answers the question and the time elapsed, you may post a new question with additional details for the new requirement and  upvote this answer??. I will  try to answer it there if possible..

Comment: Ok. I answered anyway. Please let me know your feedback.